# Cannot Connect to MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have been doing some work with MySQL recently and needed to use InnoDB. I checked to see if it was installed and switched on using: `mysqladmin variables | grep have_innodb`. It said no so i went into `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and commented out `–skip-innodb`

After i restarted and tried to log in I am getting the following issue:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2)

Comment: When you say you tried to log in, how are you doing it? Command-line `mysql` or via another application?

Comment: Is your client and server expecting the same socket? (`socket` option in the configuration files)

Comment: did you check the mysql logs for errors while starting?

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are seeing is most likely caused by the mysqld service not running. You can test this with

```
service mysqld status
mysql start/running, process 13632
```

or more likely in your case

```
service mysqld status
mysql stop/waiting
```

There are many reasons why your mysql might not be running, you'll most likely find more information about why in the error log `/var/log/mysql/error.log`